# How do I setup special constraints in Matlab Genetic Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, constraints, genetic

I'm solving a optimized work schedule with Genetic Algorithms in Matlab. But there are some special constraints that are not just reliant on the input variable. My special constraint is as follows:

```
Input variable: x (169 elements in the vector x, integer, 1<=x<=23)
Special constraint: sum(Y.*X,2)=L (X is a 169*23 matrix based on the input variable x, Y is a 169*23 mask matrix, and L is a vector like ones(169,1))
```

For example

```
x: [2 5 7 9]   =>   X:[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
                       0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
                       0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
                       0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
Y:[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0   =>  First element in x can be 1, 2, 3, and 8
   1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0   =>  Second element in x can be 1, 2, 7, and 8
   0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1   =>  Third element in x can be 3, 4, 5, 6, and 9
   1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1]  =>  Forth element in x can be 1, 4, 5, 8, and 9
```

How do I set the special constraint in Matlab Genetic Algorithm?

Thank you!

Jsearcher